# paintComponent how to setColor from outside

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcolorchooser

I have a little problem on my project, I don't know how to handle the setColor option in this case I try to.
The main Problem is that I can't give the color to the paintComponent ore I don't know how to do that. I create an object from Scatterplot (Scatterplot sp = new Scatterplot) did not work.

here is my code for the plotPanel.

```
public class Scatterplot extends JPanel {

    List<Double> values_x = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> values_y = new ArrayList<>();

    protected double maxValue_x, minValue_x, maxValue_y, minValue_y;


    public Scatterplot(List<Double> variableValues_1, List<Double> variableValues_2) {
        values_x = variableValues_1;
        maxValue_x = Collections.max(values_x);
        minValue_x = Collections.min(values_x);

        values_y = variableValues_2;
        maxValue_y = Collections.max(values_y);
        minValue_y = Collections.min(values_y);

    }



    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        int m = 30;
        double width = getWidth();
        double height = getHeight();

        double x1 = (width-2*m) / (maxValue_x - minValue_x);
        double y1 = (height-2*m) / (maxValue_y - minValue_y);

        for (int i = 0; i < values_x.size(); i++) {
            double value_x = values_x.get(i);  
            double value_y = values_y.get(i);

            g.fillOval((int)(2*m + x1*(value_x-minValue_x)-2*m), (int)(height - (y1*(value_y-minValue_y))-2*m), 2*m, 2*m);

        }
    }      
}
```

The JColorChooser is implemented here:

```
public class GuiOptionPanel extends JPanel {


    public GuiOptionPanel(DataModel dataModel) {
        JPanel optionPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7,1));

        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel menuLabel = new JLabel("Menu");
        menuLabel.setFont(menuLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        menuPanel.add(menuLabel);
        optionPanel.add(menuPanel);

        JButton setColorButton = new JButton("Set Color");
        optionPanel.add(setColorButton);
        setColorButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            JColorChooser.showDialog( null, "Color", null );
        });

        add(optionPanel);
    }
}
```

That is all (and some more Panels) added to a Frame:

```
public GuiFrame(DataModel dataModel) {
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HIGHT);
    /**
     * Create Objects
     */
    GuiInfoPanel ip = new GuiInfoPanel(dataModel);
    GuiOptionPanel op = new GuiOptionPanel(dataModel);
    JComponent sp = new Scatterplot(dataModel.getVariableValues(0), dataModel.getVariableValues(1));
    JComponent hg1 = new Histograms(dataModel.getVariableValues(0));
    JComponent hg2 = new Histograms(dataModel.getVariableValues(1));
    /**
     * Create Panels
     */
    createMainPanel();

    /**
     * Add Panels
     */
    this.add(mainPanel);
    this.add(ip, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    menuPanel.add(op, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    scatterplotPanel.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    histogram1.add(hg1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    histogram2.add(hg2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

The daterModel Class (This is returned by an Interface):

```
package dataplotproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataModel {

    List<Variable> listOfEveryVariable = new ArrayList<>();
    String fileName = "";

    public DataModel(List<Variable> listOfEveryVariable2, String fileName2) {
        listOfEveryVariable = listOfEveryVariable2;
        fileName = fileName2;
    }

    public List<Variable> getVariables() {
        return listOfEveryVariable;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public List<String> getVariableNames() {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Variable obj : listOfEveryVariable) {
            names.add(obj.getName());
        }
        return names;
    }

    public List<Double> getVariableValues(int i){
       return listOfEveryVariable.get(i).getValueList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you probably want to do this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
[..]
}
```

In other words, a component is painted by its Graphics object, which handles things like color.

Comment: I have an JColorChooser in "public class GuiOptionPanel extends JPanel" and I want to set the color from there to the paintComponent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question with lots of plausible answers: here's one way to do it:

1. Provide a `Color` instance variable in the Scatterplot (with a setter method and default color value)
2. Use (1) to set the color in Scatterplot's paintComponent method before rendering eg `g.setColor(myColor);`
3. Pass a reference of the `Scatterplot` object to `GuiOptionPanel`
4. In ActionListener implementation within `GuiOptionPanel`, the `JColorChooser.showDialog` method returns a Color object. Assign that to a variable. `Color chosenColor = JColorChooser.showDialog( null, "Color", null );`
5. Pass color from (4) to the setter method of the `Scatterplot` from (1) and (3)

Note that the Color returned from JColorChooser.showDialog may be null if the user cancelled - should add a conditional to make sure it is not `null`. You should also call `repaint` in the color setter method of (1) if you want the color change to take immediate affect.

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that I can't create an object Scatterplot sp = new Scatterplot my IDE says "constructor Scatterplot in class Scatterplot cannot be applied to give types"

Comment: This seems to be a problem unrelated to your question. The `Scatterplot` class has a constructor that accepts 2 lists - are you passing the correct data type? (your `DataModel` class is not posted, so we can't tell)

Comment: I added the dataModel class

Comment: Quick glance I don't see anything in the current code that would result in that compiler error. Are you trying to create a Scatterplot object elsewhere without the requisite parameters? (again this seems to be an unrelated question).